# How to setup an encrypted voip structure?

Tags: software-recommendation, encryption, voip

What is the simplest way to set up a voip structure in a Linux machine with the following features:

1) Using free software

2) For computer-to-computer calls: end-to-end encryption set by the users, unpaid, no central authority (so skype is out)

3) For computer-to-phone calls: paid or unpaid, desirable encryption on the computer side if that is even possible

4) Ability to have a number to receive calls from regular phones

My research concluded that the sip protocol is the most popular. However most discussions I've read on sip are too technical and I felt it discourages the regular user who wants to just click and talk. So I put the question above and created some separate questions about [privacy with sip registrars](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15917/can-sip-registrars-eavesdrop), [privacy with voip suppliers](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15918/can-providers-of-voip-plans-eavesdrop), [what to look for in a sip registrar](https://superuser.com/questions/435307/what-should-someone-look-for-when-selecting-a-sip-registrar), [what to look for in a voip provider](https://superuser.com/questions/435318/what-are-good-sources-and-criteria-for-selecting-voip-providers).

As for the software, I noticed most software either don't provide encryption (eg `Ekiga`) or the software doesn't work nicely and [the project is abandoned](https://superuser.com/questions/183978/open-source-encrypted-voip-service#comment502179_183988) (eg `Twinkle`), so no option seemed satisfying.

Comment: One of the actively developed VOIP clients is Jitsi, at jitsi.org. It should satisfy most of the needs mentioned above. I think that getting a local number is not up to the client program, but rather a service provider of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I use SFLPhone
its actively developed, feature rich supports sip/iax , and has signaling and voice encryption (srtp)

[SFL PHone](http://sflphone.org/)

It also has support for IP2IP calls.

If you want that to be encrypted i think you will have to set up your own encryption.

have a look at:

[OpenVPN video howtos](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/videos.html)